Flutter: Integrate front end to API with parameters
Currently, I have complete my frontend design. Now I want to call the API to submit the data. When user click "Submit" button, it will pass all the inputted data and call API to insert to database. How to call API with all parameters in flutter? This is my attempt.
Future <void> _submitData() async {
          final url = Uri.parse('http://xxxx/xxxAPI/api/hotel/InsertHotelDailyRevenue?hotel=BW&RptDate=2024/05/30&TotalRooms=1&OccupiedRooms=1&OccupancyRate=1&ADR=1&RevPAR=1&TotalRoomRevenue=1&TotalFnBRevenue=1&TotalRevenue=1');

          //Data to be sent to the API
          final Map<String, dynamic> data = {
            'hotel': 'DoubleTree',
            'RPTDate': _dateController.text,
            'TotalRooms': 299,
            'OccupiedRooms': _occRoomController.text,
            'OccupancyRate': occRate,
            'ADR': _adrController.text,
            'RevPAR': RevPAR,
            'TotalRoomRevenue': roomRevenue,
            'TotalFnBRevenue': FNBRevenue,
            'TotalRevenue': TotalRevenue,
          };

          try {
            final response = await http.post(
              url,
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              },
              body: jsonEncode(data),
            );


and, what went wrong !! where's the problem

You are using body to send the data. So, your URL should be: "http://xxxx/xxxAPI/api/hotel/InsertHotelDailyRevenue"

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
